# Unable to search unrecognizable DateTime format in Jira Lucene index

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, jira, luke

I am trying to perform a date range search on a Lucene index generated by Atlassian Jira. I have found serveral guides on how to do range queries (such as [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-range-query.html) guide), typically resulting in queries similar to:

```
customfield_10106:[2010-01-10-00-00-00 TO 2020-12-10-00-00-00]
```

However, the DateTime format in the index seems encoded somehow, and the above query therefore does not work.

**Example of dates to be queried**

The DateTime values are stored as shown in the following picture from [Luke](https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/):

[image]

Here is a closeup:

[image]

Here is what the first result looks like from the IntelliJ debugger:

[image]

**How to query these dates?**

Again, I need to make a range query for these dates, something similar to:

```
customfield_10106:[2010-01-10-00-00-00 TO 2020-12-10-00-00-00]
```

How can I perform such a query given the format of the dates in the Lucene index?

*For the reference, I am working with an index created by JIRA 7.2.2, with Lucene 3.3.0, programming in Java 8.*

Comment: is this view generated by luke or your code, looks like the tool has issues displaying date, `created` column is also filled with these characters?

Comment: The view is created by Luke, and the Created field is indeed also a date of this format.